# How to clean view private files using Teamcity?

Tags: batch-file, teamcity

I am using this code to clean the view private files through Teamcity.

```
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('cleartool lsprivate') 
DO
(del '%%i')
```

I am getting error **"i was unexpected at this time."**.

To escape the % character I am using double percentage symbol(%%). As per the TC documentation If we want to use % character in our scripts then we need to use %% character. Team city will treat it as a single Percentage % character.

I want to execute this code against WINDOWS.

Any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Try removing ' single quotation mark '  from `%%i`

Comment: In addition, replace the line-break after the `DO` by a space.

Comment: @darkfang I tried your suggestions. But I am getting the same error.

Comment: for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('cleartool lsprivate') 
DO 
(del %%i)

Answer (score 2):

- The opening parenthesis and `do` should be on the same line with `for`
- Doublequotes should be used for the path in `del`

---

```
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('cleartool lsprivate') DO (
    del "%%i"
)
```

Comment: I tried the same as you given but I am getting the same error "i was unexpected at this time."

Comment: Then there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: V:\%env.WinCCView%\app_nt     
And i am Running a custom script from TeamCity.
And i am using the above code.

Comment: Maybe Teamcity interprets `%%` as `%` or even strips it entirely. Try doubling it everywhere `%%%%i`.

Comment: _It gave :  The syntax of the command is incorrect._

`for /F "delims=" %%%%i IN ('cleartool lsprivate') 
DO 
del '%%%%i'`

Comment: Is there alternate to do the same? I want to perform the operations using TeamCity only. I am able to perform the same from command line.

Comment: You've used single quotes again which is wrong syntax and was pointed out in the answer.